# Safe to switch from warm to high on poultry in crock pot

Tags: safety

I put 6 fresh Foster Farms ‘legs’ (drumstick attached to thigh) , with skin removed, into my daughters crockpot , along with onion, celery, fresh herbs and filled with water to make my good chicken soup. I expected to wake up to that beatiful aroma, and was puzzled at what went wrong. Unknowingly, I set the crockpot on warm! That was at 10:00pm. I turned it to high at 6:00 am. I can’t find anything online regarding this. Will the dangerous backteria be killed off or should I just toss it, to ward off any food poisoning?

[image]

Comment: I've linked you to the two main duplicates for this. Basically, the warm setting is *probably* below 140F, and it's been way over 4 hours, so it's probably unsafe.

Comment: Warm is not under 140F on either of mine but it is not likely to bring raw food to 140F in 4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Warm not low? I would toss. Chances are you had high levels of pathogens before switching to high and not all toxins from bacteria are destroyed by heat.